# Search result not kept when browsing back

Tags: asp.net-mvc, browser-history

I have a search page that uses jQuery to populate a table with search results. Search.aspx is the main page and the data is added from SearchAdd.ascx.
I decided to recreate my project and so I manually copied everything from one project to the other. Everything works and looks the same in both projects except for this thing. When I've done a search, browsed to a search result and then hit the back button in the browser, I don't get the previous search results any more.

So my question is, what do I look for?
I've checked that these are exactly the same on both projects:

- `viestatemode="Enabled"`
- jQuery scripts
- global.asax
- web.config

What else is there to look for? Could have anything to do with the virtual directory?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I m surprised why its working for you in first project if you are not using some history plugin to push your ajax calls in browser history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It had to do with the jQuery version.

In my old project I used `jquery-1.4.4.min.js` and in the new I used `jquery-1.5.1.min.js`. Switched back and the history is kept when hitting the back button.

I don't know why though?

Answer (score 1):

browser back button has nothing to do with what you have tested for. it is simply client side. it shows the thing from the browser's history, unless you have not altered the behaviour of the back button.